# Reading Javascript Cookies from a subdomain

Tags: javascript, cookies

On a subdomain -- a.test.com -- I'm trying to read the cookies set at .test.com.  If I use document.cookie in JS, all i'm getting are the cookies from a.test.com.  What is the syntax or route to read the cookies from .test.com?

I'm pretty certain you can read up -- from sub domain to fqdn -- but you can not read down -- fqdn to sub domain.

Thanks!

Comment: you should use example.com, or the .example TLD, for sample URLs -- as suggested in RFC 2606 [http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2606.html]

Answer (score 10):

While setting the cookies at <del>test.com</del> example.com, make sure that you specify the cookie domain as <del>".test.com"</del> ".example.com".

For example:

```
your_key_name=your_key_value;domain=.example.com;expires=...
```

Comment: Ates, that's the thing, I don't want to do any setting. I just want to read. All the setting is being done server side from another application.

Comment: Ates is saying that, unless the cookie has been set properly, with the domain prefixed by a period, you won't be able to read the cookie from a subdomain

Comment: So are you saying if it is set properly, then document.cookie will implicitly read all the cookies from .a.test.com, as well as, .test.com?

Comment: Thanks Gareth for chiming in and elaborating on my rather terse answer.

Comment: not working for me. cookies set with .domain.com can't be seen from sub.domain.com using document.cookie. '.' prefix is definitely 100% there.

Comment: ...mmm, plot thickens, firebug is showing me all cookies. those on .domain.com which have an expiry and are not "HttpOnly" can be read using document.cookie

Comment: @dewd I don't know the full background on this bit, but: "This feature applies only to session-management cookies, and not other browser cookies." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie

Comment: @dewd How are you setting the domain cookies? Via JS or via an HTTP response?

Comment: @AtesGoral, thx for your response. I'm going to post a new question because I'm seeing some strange behaviour. The cookie is set by the server on a different subdomain. The client cannot see this cookie, but when I go to the server on my subdomain it can see it. Not sure if using https causes any issue?

Comment: @dewd I don't know much about the intricacies of this feature, especially across different browsers; but I'm interested in learning. Please post a link to your question if you've asked it!

Comment: @AtesGoral thx for retaining an interest in this. Passion grows expertise. Your first comment in answer to my observation was correct. HttpOnly cookies are not available to JavaScript. They are available to the server though. The solution was to use an ajax call to the server to get at it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to pass a Shopify variable to a subdomain using a cookie and I was able to add this Javascript before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
  var nowCart = new Date();
  var timeCart = nowCart.getTime();
  var expireTimeCart = timeCart + 1000*36000;
  nowCart.setTime(expireTimeCart); // " + nowCart.toUTCString() + "
  document.cookie = "_count={{ cart.item_count }};domain=.example.com;expires=;SameSite=none;Secure=true";
</script>
```

Using the `.` before the domain is what allowed the cookie to be read from the domain as well as any other subdomain. This should work vice-versa too.

Before the closing `</body>` tag of the subdomain, this is the Javascript I used to read the cookie and do something with it:

```
<script>
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
var cookie_name = getCookie('_count');
var cartCount = document.getElementById('_count');
cartCount.innerHTML=cookie_name;
</script>
```