# JavaScript domain read cookie from subdomain

Tags: javascript, cookies, subdomain

I have a simple question - is there any way to read subdomain cookie on main domain by JavaScript?
For example: I set cookie 'hello' with value '2' in subdomain yeah.something.com and after that I want to read it on something.com.
I tried to find answer for that but I found only information how to set cookie on subdomain by creating it on domain.

Comment: Set the `domain` parameter when setting the cookie to `.something.com`.

Comment: So the subdomain cookie should include 'domain' parametr?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Javascript Cookies from a subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688941/reading-javascript-cookies-from-a-subdomain)

Comment: I've answered a [similar (possibly duplicate?) question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67580590/15421144) that seems like it would help in this situation as well.

Answer (score -1):

An ancient question, but better to have it answered
You can do it by creating a cookie on the domain with a dot on the start to support reading from all subdomains and from the main domain as well:

```js
document.cookie = "_id=MY_ID;domain=.example.com;expires=;SameSite=none;Secure";
```

Hope it will help other lookers like me :)

Comment: Browsers stopped recognizing the leading dot in `domain=` back in 2011 when RFC 6265 was adopted, so your information is very out of date: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20884869/159145 - from the spec: _"Note that a leading `%x2E` ("."), if present, is ignored"_