# Can't get data from database trough ajax call "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do an ajax GET call to get some information out of my database. Offline (trough localhost) everything works perfectly. Online I get the same error over and over again:

"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
As you can see on following link: http://d.pr/i/pHR4

The javascript code:

```
    function loadnewsong(){

    var url = "http://www.sonder.be/?nextsong=true&id=" + $('#musicid').text();

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: url,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            $('#title').fadeOut(function(){

            $('#title').text(data[0].title);
                $('#title').fadeIn();
            });

            $('#musicid').text(data[0].id);

            audio.pause();
            $('#srcmp3').attr('src',"assets/media/" + data[0].mp3);
            $('#srcogg').attr('src',"assets/media/" + data[0].ogg);
            audio.load();
            audio.play();

            url = "http://www.sonder.be/?nextsong=true&id=" + $('#musicid').text();

        }
    });
}
```

What can I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: The [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) prevents you from getting data from external domains.

Comment: @adeneo It's the same domain www.sonder.be

Comment: but sonder.be and www.sonder.be , so different domain, it's different sub-domain

Comment: Same domain, different hostname. The same origin policy requires matching hostnames (and ports, and schemes).

Comment: @web2students.com Yes, that is correct, they are not external domains, just different subdomains?

Comment: They are different origins, therefore it violates the same-origin policy. different subdomain makes it a different origin. use a domain-relative url.

Comment: use same sub-domain also , if not possible read it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903650/javascript-domain-read-cookie-from-subdomain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sonder.be` is asking the browser to get data from `www.sonder.be` and `www.sonder.be` isn't giving it permission to share that data with `sonder.be`.

Since these are, presumably, different hostnames that point to the same site, you have wto simple approaches to fix this:

1. Pick one of the two host names to be canonical and issue `301` redirects for all resources on the other to it.
2. Use relative URIs.

Further reading:

- [The Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)
- [Ways to circumvent the same origin policy](/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)