# How to edit existing cookies in subdomains?

Tags: javascript, cookies

If a subdomain of lol.com has a cookie named "a" with value "a" and that has a domain of .lol.com how would you edit that cookie from lol.com if you have a console open in it (using JS console from inspect element in chrome).
Also would it be possible to edit it too if the cookie's domain was a.lol.com? They are both https://

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Javascript Cookies from a subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688941/reading-javascript-cookies-from-a-subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

Before adding a new cookie you must assign it to specific domain.

Example:

This function helps you to easily add cookies:

```
function setCookie(cName, cValue, cExpireInDays, cDomain){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (cExpireInDays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + "; " + expires + ";domain="+cDomain+";";
}
```

From ***sub.lol.com*** open console and add new cookie by calling the ***setCookie*** function

```
setCookie("Test", "TestValue", 4, "lol.com");
```

Go to ***lol.com*** open another time the console, and write `document.cookie` you will get the following data:

```
"Test=TestValue; OTHER_COOKIES..."
```

If you want edit it you must add a new cookie with the same domain as we did before ***or*** just call the `setCookie` function.